# Vertically align content inside XY-Grid Cell

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Using ZURB Foundation XY-Grid, I want to vertically center a cell's content, while still being able to have the cells fill the total height of the grid (for each cell to have it's own background image), which doesn't allow using the class ".align-middle" on the parent grid, since the cell height is then collapsed.

I want to be able to do this with a solid solution that will work on many different types of content, where you don't know the name and the height of the grid, so I am not looking for some specific hacks.

I have tried making the cell a flex-container, by adding the class ".flex-container", this allows me to add a class to vertically align the content, but I am hesitant to move away from the intended use of XY-grid, since it may create some other challenges that I am not forseeing now.

```
<div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x" style="height: 100px;">
                <div class="cell small-6 this-cell-has-background-and-need-to-stretch">
                    This is the text I want vertically center
                </div>
                <div class="cell small-6 this-cell-has-background-and-need-to-stretch">
                    This is the text I want vertically center
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The code above renders the cells correctly but with the text at the top of the cell.

Comment: Why not just use CSS Grid?

Comment: @symlink For wider browser support.

Comment: CSS Grid has side support: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: Zurb said that the future of CSS Grid is promising, but that for production now you'd want to use the flexbox grid, since support for css grid is too limited.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XY-Grid but this article gives just about every option for vertically+horizontally centering stuff with CSS: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need another grid-x and an align-middle on the containers that have the background. The div inside those will be centered. Like so:

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x" style="height: 100px;">
        <div class="cell small-6 grid-x align-middle" style="background:green;">
            <div>This is the text I want vertically center</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell small-6 grid-x align-middle" style="background:red;">
            <div>This is the text I want vertically center</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a great idea. I used a grid-y instead to have the elements within the cell to stack vertically. The only downside is that the helper classes gets a bit confusing, since align-top is actually left in that case, and align-bottom is right, and the other way around. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I have not used grid-y at all yet so I didn't realize that was the case -- that seems like bad semantics to me. I'm glad my solution worked for you.

Comment: how would you then tackle to get the elements to stack vertically instead of horisontally then if it is more than one child element in the cell?